# the this pointer dissapears in foreach loop

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a typescript class and it has a member function and a member variable. Before a `forEach` loop, I can check the `this` pointer and it is valid. Inside the loop, when I refer to it, it is null.

```
public getTypes(vitalsModel) : Array<any> {
    var vitals = _.get(vitalsModel, 'data');
    if (_.isEmpty(vitals) || !_.isArray(vitals)) {
        return [];
    }

    // the this pointer is valid
    _.forEach(vitals, function (vital) {
        let setting = _.get(vitalsModel, key);

        // here the this pointer is null.
        this.generalSettings.push(setting);

        console.log(keys);
        rows.push(keys);
        loc++;
    });

    return rows;
}
```

Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: Please use standard `// code comments` to add inline code descriptions.

Comment: I don't know what `_` is referring to in your code, but in standard `forEach` implementations, you can pass an object as the second argument to set the `this` value. So `_.forEach(vitals, function(vital) { ... }, this)`.

Comment: Or just use an arrow function. `_.forEach(vitals, vital => { ... })`

Comment: The issue comes down to understanding how `this` works in JS, but with arrow functions, it's a non-issue, since they don't define a `this`, so it uses the value that it closed over.

Comment: Since you're using typescript, just go for `for (var vital of vitals)`